# how to overwrite portion of one string with another starting from a given position?

Tags: c++, string

I mean the way that is done in editors with insert key on.

So having string like:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The effect will be:

```
~~~~~~~~~~Hello!~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

that is without changing length of the string.

Comment: Try `std::string::replace()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overwriting a portion of a string is done with one of the several overloads of `std::string`'s [`replace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/) member function, for example:

```
    string str = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";
    string rep = "Hello!";
    cout << str.replace(5, rep.size(), rep) << endl;
```

You can play with this example at ideone [[link]](http://ideone.com/Gzb60).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to use `std::copy`, with the
appropriate iterators:

```
std::copy( newText.begin(), newText.end(), str.begin() + n );
```

Just be sure that the target string is big enough.

Comment: I'd say a specialized function just for this purpose would be "better" per se. Of course `copy` is more general, and can be used for other things just as easily.

Comment: @chris But since such a specialized function doesn't exist... Do you think it worth writing one?